# filtering array with multiple conditions upon click (checkbox elements)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't figure it out how to set a filter that compares an array of objects with an array. I don't even know if it is possible. Here is a bit of the data and what I'm attempting to do:

The filters come from a number of checkboxes in my ui. Below and example:

the strings are characteristics and the number is the height.

```
const filter = ["moto", "gre", "sm"]
```

```
const arrayOfData = [{id: 1, characteristics: ['motorbike', 'green', 'small'],

}, {id: 2, characteristics: ['car', 'large', 'black']}, {id: 3, characteristics: ['motorbike', 'yellow', 'large']]
```

The result should throw those which arrays contain the initial letter, in the case above. I have tried using some() and include() but I can't work it out!

Comment: please add your code so we know where you got stuck

Comment: something like `arr.find(item=>loop_through_its_content_and_check_it_match_the_prefix(filter,item.char))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it combination of array [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as well as [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method and check prefix with [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method.

```js
const arrayOfData = [
  { id: 1, characteristics: ['motorbike', 'green', 'small'] },
  { id: 2, characteristics: ['car', 'large', 'black'] },
  { id: 3, characteristics: ['motorbike', 'yellow', 'large'] },
];

const filter = ['moto', 'gre', 'sm'];
const ret = arrayOfData.filter(
  (x) =>
    x.characteristics.filter((y) => filter.some((z) => y.startsWith(z)))
      .length > 0
);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for and actually made me realise that I have a problem with my data. As you see, it throws small and medium, I need to change this, but thanks for the push!